# When to NOT use a message broker such as RabbitMQ in a micro-services architecture?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

I am new to the concept of messaging brokers such as RabbitMQ and wanted to learn some best practices.

RabbitMQ seems to be a great way to facilitate asynchronous communication between micro-services, however, I have a beginners question that I could not find an answer to anywhere else.

When would one **NOT** use a message broker such as RabbitMQ in a micro-services architecture?

As an example:

Let's say I have two services. Service **A** and Service **B** *(auth service)*

The client makes a request to service **A** which in turn must communicate with service **B** *(auth service)* to authenticate the user and authorize the request. (using Basic Auth)

```
           Internet                
Client ----------------> Service A +-------> Service B [Authenticate/Authorization]
         HTTP request            HTTP or AMQP??
```

In my limited understanding, the issue I can foresee with using an AMQP in scenarios such as the one outlined above is service **A** being able to process the request and send a response to the client within an acceptable timeframe, given it must wait for service B to consume and respond to a message.

Essentially, is it a bad idea to make Service **A** wait for a response from Service **B** via an AMQP?

Or have I missed the point of an AMQP entirely??

Comment: I personally like to stay away from message brokers due the added complexity (less moving parts the better imho). I simply use grpc for inter-service communications in a synchronous manner mostly. when asynchrony is required, the recipent service will simply create a db record (add a task to an internal queue) and return a response instantly. for example queing up emails to be sent. only time I work with message brokers is when each microservice is maintained by its own team of developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually what you are describing is mostly close to the HTTP.

HTTP is synchronous which means that you have to wait for a response. The solution to this issue is AMQP as you mention. With AMQP you don't necessarily need to wait(you can configure it).

Its not necessarily a bad idea but what most microservices depend on is something called eventual consistency. As this will be a quite long answer with a lot of ifs I would suggest taking a look into [Microservices Architecture](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/e-book/microservices-architecture/pdf)

For example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture#communication-types) is the part about the http vs amqp since its mostly a question about sychronous vs asychronous communication
It goes into great detail about different approaches of microservices design listing pros and cons for your specific question and others.

For example in your case the Auth would happen at the API gateway as its not considered best practice to leave the microservices open for all the client applications.

Comment: Please explain? "For example in your case the Auth would happen at the API gateway as its not considered best practice to leave the microservices open for all the client applications."

Comment: Again not so much of a global option. But this is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture#communication-types).

Generally the whole idea of an API gateway is to act as the middleman so the outside services wont be exposed. This has disadvatanges and advatages but if you go with that pattern your API gateway handles auth issues (with the help of some services if needed).

Comment: Ok, so let's move away from authentication stuff (although thanks for the clarification on this). Say Service B handles something else Service A needs before it can respond to the client, would you use AMQP or HTTP? Is AMQP best used for jobs that are not essentially time-limited?

Comment: If Service A needs to wait for the result from Service B before it can proceed then a message queue is exactly what you don't want - a synchronous call is more suitable (such as http)